# Non-parametric test that handles ties in data?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I have two data sets (below), I want to apply the appropriate statistical test to determine the probability that the two data sets come from the same distribution. I don't believe I can use the Mann–Whitney U test because there are ties in the data.

```
data1 = c(41, 41, 29, 41, 41, 31, 31, 41, 41, 41,
    22, 41, 41, 41, 72, 41, 41, 24, 41, 23,
    41, 23, 41, 45, 34, 31, 34, 41, 31, 29,
    41, 31, 44, 23, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41,
    41)

data2 = c(1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  1, 10,  2,  2,
    13, 20,  1,  1,  2,  4, 18,  2,  4,  3, 
    2,  2,  2, 15,  2, 18,  1,  2,  2,  2,
    17, 2, 20, 20, 18, 17,  2,  2,  2, 2, 4)
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  Your question, as it stands, has awkward sentence construction and is difficult to understand.  Please read [How to Ask](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and re-word the question to describe what the problem exactly is.

Comment: Typically significance tests don't permit us to make probabilistic statements like the one you're after.  They give us some grounds for concluding that a given hypothesis is false, but usually we don't actually attach a probability to that hypothesis.

Comment: Fair. I just meant that I wanted to get a p-value for the null hypothesis that those two data sets very unlikely to be drawn from same distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Mann-Whitney U test but you can't simply ignore the existence of ties, especially when there are a lot of them.

First some general points. I'll address some points relevant to your specific data set at the end.

**Mann-Whitney with ties**

1. In small samples you can compute the exact permutation distribution of the observed ranks. If you have an extreme-enough sample you can compute p-values for larger samples. (Some software uses special algorithms to take the exact calculations out a fair way and give exact p-values for the tail even in relatively large samples, in reasonable time.)
2. In larger samples you can either sample the permutation distribution of the ranks (use a randomization test) or you can use a normal approximation (which has a smaller variance because of the ties).
3. Another possibility: (a) in cases where the data are continuous data that have been rounded/binned (so that if you had the original unbinned data there would be no ties), if all of the ties are within-group rather than across groups, you could break ties arbitrarily, assigning integer ranks to the tied values in any fashion. (b) if you have continuous data that has been rounded, and *almost* all ties are within-group, so only a few ties run across-groups, then you can break those cross-group ties randomly multiple times and see what the variation in possible p-values might be.

An alternative nonparametric test would simply be to perform a permutation test on your original data rather than on the ranks.

---

**What hypothesis tests don't tell us about**

An issue aside from your main question, but an important issue to be clear on. You said:

> determine the probability that the two data sets come from the same distribution

As dsaxton points out in comments, hypothesis tests don't tell you this probability; they can sometimes tell you when the data are inconsistent with having come from the same distribution (but still not as a probability; that would require an application of something like Bayes' rule)

---

**Brief comment on R**

Since you appear to have your data in R, the vanilla R function to do Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (`wilcox.test`) uses a normal approximation in the presence of ties, which adjusts the variance for the effect of ties. This is mentioned in the help, but you can see it in the code as well (`stats:::wilcox.test.default`); there are other R packages which are relevant (e.g. see package `coin` on CRAN, in particular its several vignettes have a lot of detail).

---

**Your sample**

However, note that your samples have *no overlap*, so no arrangement of values will have a more extreme test statistic in that direction. You could actually calculate the p-value *by hand* if you compute the "equally-extreme" cases and divide by the total number of arrangements.

Answer (score 2):

Glen_b's excellent answer describes how to apply the Mann-Whitney U test to your data (which you can do, with standard modifications).

But other nonparametric tests you might want to consider the [Cramer-von Mises criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion) and the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). The first can also be easily modified to handle ties, and the latter is insensitive to them.

Comment: +1 for the mention of tests relevant to the mentioned null hypothesis (equality of distribution). What is the basis for asserting that the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is insensitive to ties?

Comment: @Glen_b The KS statistic is unaffected because you're just finding the supremum between two CDFs, the width of any particular section of the CDF won't affect the supremum. Compare to methods where it matters how many points are below--then how you decide to split ties can affect the statistic and thus the test result. I don't understand the derivation of the test well enough to guarantee that datasets which can have ties don't cause problems, but it's not an obvious requirement the way it is for other tests.

Comment: (I mean, trivially any continuous distribution *could* have ties, with vanishingly low probability.)

Comment: Are you saying you just don't see how the potential for ties would impact the distribution of the test statistic? (It does)

Comment: I definitely see that the distribution being discrete instead of continuous affects the distribution, and discrete distributions where ties are ruled out would also affect the distribution. (At that point, why even use KS instead of MW?) But the KS statistic (and test) are built for continuous distributions, where ties could exist, and so I'm not seeing the dependence you're mentioning. Can you point me to a more in-depth explanation somewhere?

Comment: Both M-W and K-S are "built for" continuous distributions in exactly the same way. In small samples you can deal with ties in the same way (condition on the pattern of observed ties and compute the permutation distribution), but in large samples you don't have a normal approximation for the K-S where you can just compute the effect on the parameters of that distribution like you can with M-W. As for why you'd want to use K-S instead of M-W, the obvious one is because M-W can't test for all the kinds of difference in distribution that K-S can.